# Mostrar OK en ves del valor 1

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Necesito mostrar la palabra `OK` en vez del valor `1`

```
<div className="size-boton mt-0  " style={{color:miscolores[i]}} >                                                    

   {data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value}                                                                      
   <span className="opacity-6  pl-0 size_unidad">  {data.unity} </span>

</div>
```

Ayuda Porfa!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba con un operador ternario así: `<span className="opacity-6  pl-0 size_unidad">  { (data.unity === 1) ? "OK": "No OK" } </span>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Todo lo que necesitas es controlar mediante un ternario si se cumple cierta condición y renderizar una cosa u otra dependiendo del caso.

```
<div className="size-boton mt-0  " style={{color:miscolores[i]}} >                                                    

{data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value}                                                                      
<span className="opacity-6  pl-0 size_unidad">  {data.unity === 1 ? 'OK' : 'No Ok'} </span>
```

Tambíen puedes crear una variable con esa condición y utilizarla en el render, eso a gustos:

```
const isUnityOk = data.unity === 1 ? 'OK' : 'No Ok';
```

Y utilizarla tal cual

```
<span className="opacity-6  pl-0 size_unidad">  {isUnityOk} </span>
```

Comment: <div className="size-boton mt-0  " style={{color:miscolores[i+4]}} >                                                    
                                                                                {(data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value === 1 ) ? "ON": data.measurements[data.measurements.length-1].value}
                                                                                    <span className="opacity-6  pl-0 size_unidad">  {data.unity} </span> </div> 
Asi logre pero ahora tengo otro problema si quiero que el valor sea 0 marcar OFF

Comment: Si te ha servido de ayuda te agradecería que marcaras la respuesta como válida, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La manera mas simple para que no sobre cargues de lógica tu código es usar el **operador ternario** que es una sintaxis acortada de un condicional, que puede ser simple o tan complejo como lo necesites.

Estructura de un operador ternario

```
(variable === 1) ? "Resultado si es cierto": "Resultado si es falso"
```

Entonces deberías crearla de este modo:

```
<span className="opacity-6 pl-0 size_unidad"> 
   { (data.unity === 1) ? "OK": "No OK" } 
</span>
```

- [Operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator)